# WebClient Request Extremely slow when running from Windows Service

Tags: c#, web-services, webclient

I'm trying to make a HTTP POST request to a WebAPI Controller, I am calling it from my service.  Here is the class that I am injecting into my business layer in order to make the calls:

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes calls to WebAPI
/// </summary>
public class WebApiProxy : IWebApiProxy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends HTTP POST requests to WebAPI along with post values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="apiControllerName">The name of the controller to call</param>
    /// <param name="postValues">The values to post to the controller</param>
    public void SendApiRequest(string apiControllerName, NameValueCollection postValues)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                //
                // Breakpoint below this line, it's where it hangs
                //
                byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(string.Format("http://localhost:8080/Api/{0}", apiControllerName), "POST", postValues);
                string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // TODO: Handle failed requests
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I realised that it is running extremely slowly, probably around 30 seconds for every request.

As an experiment I tried doing the request from the console in Chrome using the following code and it runs lightening fast - in the blink of an eye:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/Api/FinishedTakersCount", { "QuizOwnerUserId": 1, UrlId: "0mFjBH" }, null);
```

I also created a quick console app to test the functionality and this also runs in the blink of an eye:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to make web request, or type exit...");

            var typed = Console.ReadLine();

            if (typed == "exit")
            {
                break;
            }

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {

                    var apiControllerName = "LiveTakersCount";
                    var postValues = new NameValueCollection();
                    postValues.Add("QuizOwnerUserId", "1");
                    postValues.Add("UrlId", "0mFjBH");

                    //TODO: Remove port from localhost
                    byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(string.Format("http://localhost:8080/Api/{0}", apiControllerName), "POST", postValues);
                    string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);

                    Console.WriteLine("HTTP Request completed.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle failed requests
                    Console.WriteLine("An Exception occurred with the web request: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see the values that I am posting in the above code.

I can't for the life of me understand why it would be taking so long, just because I am running the request within a Window Service.

It is the same whether it makes the call when installed on my local machine or if I debug it within Visual Studio - **stepping over client.UploadValues(...)** takes 30 seconds or so and the result is fine.

**Why is it running slow in my Windows Service (installed or debugging in VS), but lightening fast every time when doing an AJAX request or request from a console application?**

Comment: Pause the debugger during the hang. Post the call stack with external code.

Comment: Do you think that that will reveal anything?  I pause it before the hang at `client.UploadValues` and step over it and see how long it takes.

Comment: Well, I would not ask if I did not think that. The stack tells you what the program is doing right now. Function names are usually descriptive.

Comment: It looks like changing this to HttpClient() seems to have done the trick...

Comment: I've just found that this hasn't provided me with a solution.  It still hangs once I start `await`ing the method, which isn't acceptable.  It's taking forever.  Bizarre that it's fine from everywhere else and not from the service

Comment: Is it likely to be something to do with the request being sent to localhost, the WebAPI runs on the same machine as the service sending the HTTP requests?

Comment: Just an update on this one.  In the end it was the code that was being run within the WebAPI method that was extremely slow - not the HTTP request.  I'm still not exactly sure why it was fast over the AJAX request or from the console application and not the Window Service HTTP request... that's still a bit of a mystery to me

Comment: It might have been fast because of the non-blocking issue that I commented about in the deleted answer. If you don't wait then it's quite fast indeed. If you care to find out why it's fast sometimes and slow sometimes post more information. I'm happy to take a look. It might be worthwhile to find out. Might be a bug hiding.-

Comment: I think you might be right, I think it was the non-blocking code that was making it fast.  I have the code running in live now without any async/awaits and it runs just fine - in a split second.  It was a linq query that was supposed to be executing a `Count()` but instead the way I had written it it was pulling all of the records back and __then__ counting them.